# Pasteboard not accessible when locked with passcode on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, keychain, pasteboard

I have noticed I cannot access the Pasteboard in iOS whenever my device is locked with passcode. I know there was a restriction regarding keychain, but not sure why its affecting pasteboard as well. Is this a known issue or purposeful restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is **desired function**.

Imagine an app like 1Password. That app supports copying a password to the paste/clip board.

If I have a passcode set on my device, it's probably because I don't want people to be able to see the data on that device - it could contain stuff like, say, all the specs and launch date for the next iPad.

As a user, I probably shouldn't be copying such information to the pasteboard, but, hey - my device is locked with a passcode, right? No one can see my info, right?

Apple knows that users often use this line of reasoning, and, however flawed it may be, you *build your OS for the user - not the user for your OS*.*

---

<sub>* Unless you're Microsoft building Windows 8. Then you can break all the rules and make a strange OS.</sub>